# The result of using variables and constants is not the same in c++

Tags: c++

Please look at the picture
[Wrong answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcsyl.png)
[Right answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/790cS.png)
The first which I used the variable i, and I get the wrong answer
The second which I did not use i, the result is right.
My compiler is MinGW GCC 4.7.2 32-bit, and my computer is win10 64-bit.
I feel very strange about the different results, Is this loss of accuration?
this is my file after using `gcc test.cpp -S`
the first https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TXjCPyWC9G/
the second https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FJXQDbyRFq/
Thanks in advance, by the way, forgive my poor english..

Comment: Don't post text as images.Copy and paste it into the question instead.

Comment: I can't paste it into the question because of my level

Comment: @Meepo Sure you can. Copy-pasting code is the same as writing text, and you already did that. You might not able to post images in your question, but no-one is asking you to do that.

Comment: I copied the essential code lines into the question, so when the edit is reviewed I hope they will be visible.

Comment: Though I only copied text from the images to the question text, my edit was rejected. So I put a summary of the OP's code into my answer.

Comment: The numbers 0.1, 0.2, and 0.3 looks familiar after reading this question:  [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Posting code or error messages as screenshots is a bad habit people have been picking up a lot in the last one or two years. I've also noticed it at work, in e-mails by co-workers. It is extremely annoying and frustrating; perhaps it's the bad influence of "social media" where you upload photos of stuff all the time? In any case, stop doing it. Use **text**.

Answer (score 0):

First, I summarize the two ways of computing the same numerical expression (given in images by the OP):

Correct result (“Right answer”, 9255):

```
int tmp = 10000 - (10000 - 8000) * 0.2 - 1500 * 0.03 - 3000 * 0.1;
```

Wrong result (“Wrong answer”, 9254):

```
int i = 10000;
int tmp = i - (i - 8000) * 0.2 - 1500 * 0.03 - 3000 * 0
```

The expression without the variable (“Right answer”) is computed at compile time (optimization, to save runtime), the expression with the variable `i` (“Wrong answer”) is computed at runtime. Obviously the compiler and the compiled program use different arithmetics (different rounding). (The number `0.1` has no exact binary floating point representation, so rounding is necessary.)

I cannot say why these two systems use different rounding. When I compile your “Wrong” example with `gcc` on my machine it yields the right answer.